# What configuration would allow me to keep my MySQL server(s) updated while keeping the service consistently available?

Tags: mysql, centos, redhat, replication, high-availability

I have several Centos 5 web hosting servers with local instances of MySQL that I am looking to segment so that all servers connect to a central MySQL instance. These are web applications doing more reads than writes, and I would like to keep the databases available as much as possible while also keeping the host servers updated. I've been reading the docs at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ha-overview.html which are informative, but I'd like to know what others have done in practice that have worked for them.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-Master Replication Manager for MySQL is good. http://mysql-mmm.org/